# An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<Stuff>> listened by

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, listtile

I was trying to list some data with ListTile from Firestore Database. And while pulling the data from the database, I got the exception below. The names of all the attributes in the database and code are all same. I have no idea why it throws it.

```
The following assertion was thrown:
An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<Stuff>> listened by

StreamProvider<List<Stuff>?>, but no `catchError` was provided.

Exception:
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Here is my **stuff.dart**:

```
class Stuff {
  final String title;
  final String details;
  final String price;

  Stuff({
    required this.title,
    required this.details,
    required this.price,
  });
}
```

Here is my **database.dart**:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:unistuff_main/models/stuff.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final String? uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  //collection reference
  final CollectionReference stuffCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stuffs');

//stufflist from snapshot
  List<Stuff> _stuffListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Stuff(
        title: doc.get('title') ?? '0',
        price: doc.get('price') ?? '0',
        details: doc.get('details') ?? '0',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

//get the stuffs
  Stream<List<Stuff>> get stuffs {
    return stuffCollection.snapshots().map(_stuffListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

Here is my **stuff_list.dart**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:unistuff_main/models/stuff.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:unistuff_main/screens/home/stuff_tile.dart';

class StuffList extends StatefulWidget {
  const StuffList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StuffListState createState() => _StuffListState();
}

class _StuffListState extends State<StuffList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final stuffs = Provider.of<List<Stuff>?>(context);
    //print(stuffs?.docs);
    if (stuffs != null) {
      stuffs.forEach((stuff) {
        print(stuff.title);
        print(stuff.details);
        print(stuff.price);
      });
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      //number of the items in list
      itemCount: stuffs?.length ?? 0,
      //return a function for every item in the list
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return StuffTile(stuff: stuffs![index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and **stuff_tile.dart**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:unistuff_main/models/stuff.dart';

class StuffTile extends StatelessWidget {
  //const StuffGrid({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  //sending the data to stuff
  final Stuff? stuff;
  StuffTile({this.stuff});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //creating the list view
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
        child: Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
          child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 25.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
              ),
              title: Text(stuff!.title),
              subtitle: Text(stuff!.details)
              ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Anything would help!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly be missing the dependency for **firebase_core**, which was the first issue I ran into when adding your files to a new blank project. You can run this in the terminal:

```
flutter pub add firebase_core
```

I also do not see the code listed for the error you have given (*"_MapStream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List>"*). The project runs fine for me.

You can view my project's code on [Github](https://github.com/Lerie82/stackoverflow/tree/master/untitled2).

Comment: Hi, my firebase_core is up to date and there is a dependency for it in the dependecies. Unfortunately it didn't fix my problem :( I think it work with no problem on you because your app doesnt connected to my database so it just passes that parts.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and seen different methods but i couldn't see how to implement those into my own code. So, I go with a different and more basic method, which you can read it from [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes).

So, I deleted almost all the files above. Instead of i just use the `stuff_list.dart` file as my main listing file. Then, I called it from my home.dart file. So, everything works clean at the moment.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class StuffList extends StatelessWidget {
  const StuffList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _stuffList(),
    );
  }
}

class _stuffList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Stuffs').snapshots();

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _usersStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Text("Loading");
          }

          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(data['title']),
                subtitle: Text(data['details']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

But I won't accept my answer as an answer because this is kind of unrelated to my question. Because it doesnt fix the problem i had above. It just bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

Add : `initialData: [null],` to your stream provider.